# Getting a style value for an element using watir

Tags: watir, watir-webdriver

Below is the sample tag

I would need an output for the style attribute which is "padding-left:16px;;"
Tried
@browser.td(:class, "xxxx").attribute_value("style") 
and the output I get is "" where as I was expecting "padding-left:16px;;"
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: sample tag <td class="xxxx" id="1234" style="padding-left:16px;;" ai="[&quot;c6874842903c9bed3_OP_alc195fa2647f1625b&quot;]">

Comment: Are there multiple td elements with that class? Note that `@browser.td(:class, "xxxx")` returns the first matching element. The one you are looking for might not be the first one on the page, which is why you do not get the expected value.

Comment: Yes Justin you are absolutely right, it has multiple td elements with the same class. Thanks for letting me know why it didn't give me the expected result

Answer (score 0):

Use the .style method

```
padding_left = @browser.td(:class, "xxxx").style('padding-left')
```

Comment: Thanks Van It does returns me the pixel count. Basically the same class is used multiple times and I was looking to get a list of values which has a pixel count of 16. Any suggestions?

Comment: To be more clear, the same class has values at varying pixel counts. I am only interested in the values which appear at 'style="padding-left:16px;;". The aim is basically to extract these values and sum it up.

Comment: Well you could use .tds to get all the rows that match that class, then iterate an find the ones with the style you want.  Or use .elements and select by css to get a collection of the ones that match.   See https://jkotests.wordpress.com/2012/08/28/locate-element-via-custom-attribute-css-and-xpath/ for more on selecting that way.

Comment: Thanks Van for your time. Will try out your suggestion.